# Recebendo objeto por parâmetro

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

Estou utilizando `Spring MVC` e utilizo alguns mapeamentos para receber um objeto por exemplo e acessar esse objeto específico no `controller`.

Por exemplo:

```
@GetMapping("/pessoa/{idPessoa}")
public ModelAndView editaPessoa(@PathVariable("idPessoa") Pessoa pessoa) {
.....
}
```

Sendo assim, caso eu tenha uma listagem, eu preciso passar por um link o href do controller passando o id da pessoa que eu queria editar por exemplo. Porém, eu queria ocultar o id da pessoa via browser, de modo que a url nao ficasse expondo os ids dos objetos

http://site.com.br/editar/pessoa/32

Existe alguma forma de apenas chamar o mapeamento sem passar o id por url e conseguir recuperar esse objeto dentro do controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, basta utilizar o *@RequestBody* e criar uma classe POJO que contenha um atributo de String id. Note que você não vai conseguir passar usado o href do link, portanto terá que criar uma request encaminhando o json via Javascript.

Por exemplo:

```
@GetMapping("/pessoa/")
public ModelAndView editaPessoa(@RequestBody PessoaInterface pessoa) {
.....
}
```

PessoaInterface.java

```
public class PessoaInterface {
    String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Note que em PessoaInterface.java você pode adicionar um List e repassar inúmeros IDs numa única request.

### Solução ideal

Você está utilizando o método GET para fazer uma edição. Um dos principios de REST é respeitar os códigos HTTPs e utilizar os verbos corretos, isso é, utilizar GET somente num caso em que você **precise acessar algo**. O ideal é que você utilizasse PUT ou PATCH para a edição (não posso afirmar qual com certeza porque não conheço o seu cenário).

Note que não é somente uma questão de respeitar os padrões, há uma longa thread sobre encaminhar body numa requisição GET (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) e alguns servers até recusam por padrão requests GETs com body. **Falando de REST, com certeza isso não é aceito.**

### E se quisesse obter um elemento sem ter que repassar o ID?

Supondo que o seu problema não seja uma edição de pessoa e sim obter uma pessoa repassando o ID, nesses casos continuamos repassando via *path param* mas é utilizado GUIDs ao invés de IDs.